# I'm trying to send groups.memberships.create with Identity group api in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to send `groups.memberships.create` with Identity group api in google apps script:

K

Is an error. The script is:

```
var headers = {
  'Authorization':'Bearer' + accessToken,
  'contentType':'application / json',
};

var payload = {
    "preferredMemberKey": {
      "id": "XXX@XX.XX"
    },
    "roles": [
      {
        "name": "MEMBER"
      }
    ]
  };

var options = {
  'method':'post',
  'muteHttpExceptions': true,
  'headers': headers,
  'payload': JSON.stringify (payload)
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch (url, options);
```

What should I do?

### error message is

### "error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "{"preferredMemberKey":{"id":"XXX@XXX"},"roles":[{"name":"MEMBER"}]}": Cannot bind query parameter. Field '{"preferredMemberKey":{"id":"XXX@XXX' could not be found in request message.",
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
"details": [
{
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
"fieldViolations": [
{
"description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "{"preferredMemberKey":{"id":"XXX@XXX"},"roles":[{"name":"MEMBER"}]}": Cannot bind query parameter. Field '{"preferredMemberKey":{"id":"XXX@XXX' could not be found in request message."
}
]
}
]
}
}

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Thank you very mach.Your answer was able to lead to a solution.

Comment: Thank you.Please tell me where the button is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message, I thought that in your script, `'contentType':'application / json'` is required to be modified. So, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var headers = {
  'Authorization':'Bearer' + accessToken,
  'contentType':'application / json',
};
```

#### To:

```
var headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer' + accessToken,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',  // Modified
};
```

Or

#### From:

```
var headers = {
  'Authorization':'Bearer' + accessToken,
  'contentType':'application / json',
};

var payload = {
    "preferredMemberKey": {
      "id": "XXX@XX.XX"
    },
    "roles": [
      {
        "name": "MEMBER"
      }
    ]
  };

var options = {
  'method':'post',
  'muteHttpExceptions': true,
  'headers': headers,
  'payload': JSON.stringify (payload)
};
```

#### To:

```
var headers = {  // Modified
  'Authorization':'Bearer' + accessToken,
};

var payload = {
    "preferredMemberKey": {
      "id": "XXX@XX.XX"
    },
    "roles": [
      {
        "name": "MEMBER"
      }
    ]
  };

var options = {
  'method':'post',
  'muteHttpExceptions': true,
  'headers': headers,
  'payload': JSON.stringify (payload),
  'contentType': 'application/json',  // Added
};
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your URL, request body and access token are valid. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)